# Using timeout to show and hide custom directive element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive that inherits scope from its parent controller. The directive is a div element that overlays the page for three seconds then disappears unless an up/down arrow button is clicked. The div element acts as kind of a modal. This is the code on my DOM

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="volumeVisibility">
    <display-volume-modal></display-volume-modal>
</div>
```

The default setting is `false`. When `volumeVisibility === true`, the directive will appear upon a button click. So far, so good. These are my two functions in the controller:

```
$scope.volumeVisibility = false;

$scope.timer = function(){ 
    console.log("Timer");
    $scope.volumeVisibility = false;
};

$scope.displayVolumeModal = function(){
    $scope.volumeVisibility = true;
    console.log("modal");   
};
```

The timeout works and sets `$scope.volumeVisibility === false`. However, the div does not remove itself from the page. Here is the code from the directive (I've removed the irrelevant parts):

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.$watch('volumeVisibility', function(newVal, oldVal){
            if (newVal === true){
                window.setTimeout(scope.timer, 3000);           
                document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                    //stuff
                    switch (e.which) {              
                        case 38:
                            //stuff
                            break;
                        case 40:
                            //stuff
                            break;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, true);
    },
    templateUrl: 'public/templates/displayVolumeModal.html'
}
```

I've tried putting each function into the directive or the controller. What step can I take to make this directive DIV element disappear after timeout?

Comment: Can you provide `scope.timer` function body?

Comment: this comes to mind from the first glance: try placing your `ng-show` inside `display-volume-modal` and get rid of `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens because no digest cycle was called.

To update sync, you have to run digest cycle. I think, in this case, you can use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service instead of setTimeout.

Benefits of $timeout service:

- unit testable
- $digest cycle starts after function you passed to the timeout

Comment: You got it! It was the $timeout service! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, you can use another methods to call digest cycle. Something like `$evalAsync` method in `scope` object, but I don't think it is good solution. $timeout - what you need. Also, $timeout can be easily mocked in unit tests

Answer (score 1):

`window.setTimeout(scope.timer, 3000);` does not call angular `digest` cycle, so `watch` doesn't see the changes.

Use angular's [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service instead like this:

```
$timeout(scope.timer, 3000);
```

Internally it does the same as `window.setTimeout`, but makes sure, that `digest` will be called after.

Read more about [angular digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop) and how angular checks if some variable changed. Especially the `Integration with the browser event loop` chapter.

Comment: You got it! It was the $timeout service! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ng-show and ng-hide** it will simply make the visibility hidden of the particular html element on which it is applied. The element will be there in the DOM, no matter if it's ng-hide or ng-show.
This is why the directive is not being called.

If you want to call the directive everytime it appears on the screen, simply use **ng-if** instead of **ng-show**.